# Variable does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm trying to run a while loop that keeps going through a list until the entry is null. My code looks like so:

```
int i = 0;

while(list[i] != null)
{

    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            list[i].Name
        </dt>

        <dd>
            list[i].Damage
        </dd>
    </dl>
    i++;
}
```

The error I'm getting is that `i` doesn't exist in the context of the while loop. I can't define it inside of the loop because then it will be reset to 0 on each pass through yet I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Are you using Razor ?

Comment: I am, does that normally cause issues?

Comment: What is the *exact* wording of your error message (absent any epic stack dumps)?

Comment: "The name i does not exist in the current context" is all I'm being told by Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert HTML elements into your Razor file, it escapes out of C# mode, so you need to add the `@` sign to your variable calls.

EDIT: You also need the `@` sign on the `while` and declaration statements:

```
@{ int i = 0; }

@while(list[i] != null)
{
  <dl class="dl-horizontal">
      <dt>
          @list[i].Name 
      </dt>

      <dd>
          @list[i].Damage
      </dd>
  </dl>
  i++;
}
```

This will put you back into the C# context and evaluate the expression.

Comment: That wouldn't cause an error, it would simply render `list[i].Name` as text on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring your variable inside the code block at the top of your page:

```
@{
    int i = 0;
}
```

Then :

```
@while(list[i] != null)
{

    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @list[i].Name
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @list[i].Damage
        </dd>
    </dl>
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Why would this need to be done when `i++` is "bare"?

Comment: @user2864740 if you find the answer of that, let me know :p I'm using this when I dealing with Razor in MVC and it works very well. but I'm not expert on Razor syntax.I believe that is because i++ inside of the code block,not between the HTML tags, that's why it works